# TypeError: convert_to_audio() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python

So, I am just an amateur at Python(like I am just a 12th standard beginner) and I was given a program to create a smart clock which will greet you what time it is and i had to make this program by using datetime, gtts and playsound modules. So, i created a really basic program but it is showing error that **TypeError: convert_to_audio() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**. The code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")
print("Current Time =", current_time)


def playaudio(audio):
    playsound(audio)
def convert_to_audio(self,text):
    audio=gTTS(text)
    audio.save("Textaudio.mp3")
    playaudio("textaudio.mp3")
convert_to_audio("Hello Ravi. Good Morning the time is",current_time,"Have a nice day")
```

Comment: Is the error message not clear enough? The functions expects 2 things `self, text` but got 3 things `"Hello Ravi. Good Morning the time is",current_time,"Have a nice day"`

Comment: Why is there even a `self` parameter in the function? Did you rip out that code from an example where that function was a method of a class? You should at least try to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @rdas So how do i add 3 things to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have made some mistakes which is okay. You are still learning but before writing code, always figure out the problem statement and look for a solution without code. Once you get that right, python is just another way of implementing things.

Try debugging and figure out what is happening.

```
from datetime import datetime
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound
     
def playaudio(audio):
    playsound(audio)

def convert_to_audio(text):
    audio=gTTS(text)
    audio.save("Textaudio.mp3")
    playaudio("Textaudio.mp3")

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")

convert_to_audio("Hello Ravi. Good Morning the time is {}. Have a nice day").format(current_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message states the problem pretty clearly: You are passing three arguments, i.e.,

1. `"Hello Ravi. Good Morning the time is"`
2. `current_time`
3. `"Have a nice day"`

to the `convert_to_audio` function while it expects only two, i.e.,

1. `self`
2. `text`.

You have to remove one of the arguments to get rid of that error.

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is to pass *one* string that *contains* the current time. Have a look at Python's string [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) function to solve your problem. You can get rid of the superfluous `self` argument, then, as well.

Comment: I think `self` should be removed as a parameter and the input should be one single string.

Comment: @Matthias But if it is a single string then how will the gtts and playsound modules tell the current time?

Comment: @Warmachine Did you read the answer from Raghav Gupta? Are you aware that you can combine strings to create a new string?

Comment: @Matthias   Thanks mate I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

@Raghav Gupta Thanks man I ended up using this code:-

```
from datetime import datetime
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S %p")
print("Current Time =", current_time)


def playaudio(audio):
    playsound(audio)
def convert_to_audio(Text):
    audio=gTTS(Text)
    audio.save("Textaudio.mp3")
    playaudio("textaudio.mp3")
strtime=str(current_time)
convert_to_audio("Hello Ravi. Good Morning the time is"+strtime+"Have a nice day")
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Do upvote the accepted answer as well so it reaches more audience.